# Ruby on Rails: Accessing HTML elements from model

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model

I'm trying to find a way to access html elements from my view from within my model.

I'm trying to access the the page title. On my view I have this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Baseline') %>
```

And from my model, here is my latest attempt:

```
   def steps
      if @title == 'Baseline'
         %w[sfmfa phq whoqol_bref positive_negative ]
      elsif @title == 'Treatment Completion'
         %w[smfa phq ]
      else
         %w[]
      end

   end
```

I also tried by using params[:title], but params isn't recognized in the model. This feels like a really dumb question, but I haven't been able to find a straight forward answer.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT. Adding more detail.

As mentioned below, I'm going about this wrong. So now I'm trying to pass the correct identifier from my controller, to the model.

Currently I have pagination for one page, 'Baseline'. I'm trying to allow for pagination on 2 other pages. I simply need to be able to change the value of whats held in steps.

My old 'steps' method looked like this:

subject.rb

```
def steps
     %w[sfmfa ...]
end
```

And here are what steps is used for:

```
   def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
   end

   def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]
   end

   def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]
   end

   def first_step?
    current_step == steps.first
   end

   def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
   end
```

So, I guess my new method might look something like this, where I pass the argument from the controller:

```
def steps(title)
 if title == 'Baseline'
     %w[sfmfa ...]
 elsif title == 'Other'
     %w[sma ...]
 else
     #Shouldnt get here
 end
```

Also, here is how my view renders the steps:

```
<%= render "base_#{@subject.current_step}", :f => f %>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible but it is a bad idea regardless, Your model should know *nothing* about the view it is being rendered  in. If you need different steps based on something like that state, you can use the controller to send the state to the model (and also the view).

Comment: Can you give an overview of what you're trying to do? In particular, what is the array being returned by `steps` used for?

Comment: check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked  for some more info on multi-step forms

Comment: Why do you want your steps in the model?  That looks like controller logic.

Comment: Thank you, Doon. Fortunately my multi-step form actually works just fine, it's just that I have multiple multi-step forms - and I need a way to differentiate between them.

Comment: Helios, I have steps in the model because I followed this podcast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms, and I don't know any better yet.